# MySQL: Get results from two tables, count matches in a third

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, all of which share a common field (`our_id`).

`our_id` is the primary key in Table1.

`our_id` also exists zero or more times in Table2 and Table3.

I want to select records where `our_id` exists in both Table1 and Table2, but I also need to count how many times `our_id` occurs in Table3 (or even just whether `our_id` exists or not in Table3).

I came up with this:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.*, COUNT(Table3.*) AS table3_count 
FROM Table1, Table2, Table3 
WHERE Table1.our_id = Table2.our_id 
AND Table1.our_id = Table3.our_id;
```

…but that only returns results where `our_id` exists in Table3, which it may not do.

So I tried:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.*, COUNT(Table3.*) AS table3_count 
FROM Table1, Table2, Table3 
WHERE Table1.our_id = Table2.our_id 
  AND (Table1.our_id = Table3.our_id 
       OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table3 
                      WHERE Table1.our_id=Table3.our_id));
```

But that just ran and ran…

I need it to still return results where `our_id` exists in both Table1 and Table2, and tell me how many times (or whether) it exists in Table3.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a LEFT JOIN to bring in Table3. A LEFT JOIN returns all rows from the left table (Table1) and attempts to match the rows in the right table (Table3). If Table3 does not have any rows that match, NULL is returned for the selected Table3 fields.

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.*, t3.count
FROM Table1, Table2
LEFT JOIN (SELECT our_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM Table3 GROUP BY our_id) t3
ON Table1.our_id = t3.our_id
WHERE Table1.our_id = Table2.our_id
```

Comment: That sounds like the right thing! I've just tried it though, and I'm getting an error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'Table1.our_id' in 'on clause'` but that table and field definitely exist (I've checked the spelling a dozen times now!).

Comment: Is the case correct? You might want to try giving all of the tables aliases to remedy the issue. `FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2` and then use `ON t1.our_id = t3.our_id`. I have no idea what could be wrong, but maybe one of those two things will help you out.

Comment: Ah, I got it! I had to swap around Table1 and Table2 on the `FROM` line (so the second line reads `FROM Table2, Table1`). Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it.